# I want to get minimum login time and maximum logout time using linq in one line?

Tags: asp.net

This is my controller method:

```
     var query = (from t in db.UserContext
                  orderby t.In_Time, t.Out_Time
                  group t by new { t.In_Time, t.Out_Time } into grp
                  select new
                  {
                      grp.Key.In_Time,
                      grp.Key.Out_Time,
                      hours = grp.Max(t => t.In_Time),
                      pay = grp.Min(t => t.Out_Time),

                  }).ToList();
```

But when I try to use `foreach` loop it tells me that I can not use it.
The purpose is, I want to retrieve first login time and last logout time and show 
 it in the dashboard

I want to do minimum of in time and maximum of out time through this linq query in one line.

Can anyone tell how I do it?

I want to write this code in dashboard controller, Can anyone tell me if this is correct code for my requirement?

Comment: Can you post whatever error message you get when you try to do this? "it tells me that I can not use it" is not very helpful to those of us trying to help with your problem... Also I am not sure your grouping does what you want - you are grouping by unique sin and out times which means each group will only have one in and one out time. Did you mean to group by user or perhaps not group at all to get a global smallest and largest?

Comment: Do you want `minimum of in time and maximum of out time` for each group?

Comment: var q=(from pd in dataContext.tblProducts 
 join od in dataContext.tblOrders on pd.ProductID equals od.ProductID 
 join ct in dataContext.tblCustomers on od.CustomerID equals ct.CustID 
 orderby od.OrderID 
 select new { 
 od.OrderID,
 pd.ProductID,
 pd.Name,
 pd.UnitPrice,
 od.Quantity,
 od.Price,
 Customer=ct.Name //define anonymous type Customer
 }).ToList();

Comment: // I want to join two table like this and in select new i write  hours = grp.Max(t => t.In_Time),
                      pay = grp.Min(t => t.Out_Time) from one table and By id i want to name from another table.ex grp.name...but it show error

Comment: Can you tell me how i write the code